# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir un PDF con un socket de Java?

Tags: java, spring, pdf, socket, print

Necesito saber cómo puedo mandar a impresión un archivo PDF a una impresora, direccionando con la IP correspondiente de la impresora.
Pensé en que tal vez debo buscar el modelo de la impresora y solicitar al proveedor el SDK correspondiente, pero no sé si haya alguna librería de código abierto que me permita mandar a imprimir estos documentos a una impresora X.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Para eso son los drivers. Usa el spool que tiene el OS para lidiar con la impresora que haya instalada, ya el OS se charla con el driver.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías utilizar las opciones que ofrece el sistema operativo, que es donde están configuradas las impresoras para uso de los demás aplicativos. Puedes hacerlo utilizando la clase `PrinterJob`

Te dejo un enlace con la documentación de la clase

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html)

Y este con código de ejemplo

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html